# How to stop reloading page in WebView after screen unlock

Tags: android, webview, page-refresh

I'm working on an app for Android.
When I unlock the phone it the page in my WebView refreshes.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WebviewClient methods and GoogleChromeClient methods to avoid this